# struct ** vs struct * in C. Confusion between the dereference and address-of operators

Tags: c, pointers, struct, type-conversion

I ported lwIP for Android and extracted some code from the port for Unix, and now I don't understand why the following logic can be compiled.

There are a function, a `#define`, and a `typedef`, they used in the port for Unix.
I wrote the code in **func.h**

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H
#include <stdint.h>

struct sys_sem {
    unsigned int c;
};

#define sys_mutex_t                   sys_sem_t;
typedef struct sys_sem * sys_sem_t;

void sys_arch_sem_wait(struct sys_sem **s, int timeout);

#endif
```

I also copied thier `#define`s and pasted them to **sys.h**

```
#ifndef SYS_H
#define SYS_H

#define sys_mutex_lock(mutex)         sys_sem_wait(mutex)
#define sys_sem_wait(sem)                  sys_arch_sem_wait(sem, 0)

#endif
```

And there is my function I call from Java in Android; it's in the file **com_sample_MainActivity.c**

```
#include "func.h"
#include "sys.h"

static sys_mutex_t
mem_mutex;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_sample_MainActivity_messageFromNativeCode(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
    sys_mutex_lock(&mem_mutex);
    sys_mutex_lock(121); // Even this can be compiled
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

`sys_mutex_t` is synonym of `sys_sem_t`, and `sys_sem_t` is a synonym of `sys_sem *`. Am I right?
My signature of `sys_arch_sem_wait` accepts `struct sys_sem **s. However, I pass the address of`sys_mutex_t`which after all the`#define`s means the same as passing a`sys_sem`, and the code is compiled.

Even this can be compiled

```
sys_mutex_lock(121); // Even this can be compiled. Why?
```

So I can pass anything to `sys_mutex_lock`, can't I?

**My test.**

```
#include "func.h"
#include <android/log.h>

void sys_arch_sem_wait(struct sys_sem **s, int timeout) {
    if (s == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sample", "s == NULL");
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sample", "s != NULL");
    }
    if (*s == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sample", "*s == NULL"); // It causes the failure
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sample", "*s != NULL");
    }
}
```

And here is the output of LogCat:

```
01-07 14:46:40.695: D/Sample(22086): s != NULL
01-07 14:46:40.695: D/Sample(22086): *s == NULL
```

**The expected behavior.**

I expected that

```
void sys_arch_sem_wait(struct sys_sem **s, int timeout)
```

should have the different signature

```
void sys_arch_sem_wait(struct sys_sem *s, int timeout)
```

Comment: compiled without warnings?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, there is two warnings about type incompatibility: `warning: passing argument 1 of 'sys_arch_sem_wait' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]` and `warning: passing argument 1 of 'sys_arch_sem_wait' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: and then also, you chose to _ignore_ them, right? Why? They are there for some reason isn't it? They are quite self-explaining , too. Don't blame the compiler. it did it's own job. We're the one _neglecting_ that. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I didn't ignore the warnings. If you are good at C, you could clone my repository from `https://bitbucket.org/MaksimDmitriev/norootfirewall` and run `ndk-build` in the branch `unix`. You won't see the warnings.

Comment: I did not check the link, but a blind-shot, did you cross check that warnings are enabled in later case?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I don't suppress warnings in Android.mk or Application.mk. I won't check if they are enabled or disabled in C because it would take me too long. If you make an answer out of your comments, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the macros presented, this ...

```
sys_mutex_lock(<arg>);
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
sys_arch_sem_wait(<arg>, 0);
```

... where the first argument to `sys_arch_sem_wait()` is declared to have type `struct sys_sem **`.

Yes, `sys_mutex_t` is a synonym of `sys_sem_t`.

Yes, `sys_sem_t` is a synonym of `struct sys_sem *`.

> My signature of `sys_arch_sem_wait` accepts `struct sys_sem **s`. However, I pass the address of `sys_mutex_t` which after all the `#defines` means the same as passing a `sys_sem`, and the code is compiled.

No.  You are confusing the address-of operator (`&`) with the dereferencing operator (`*`).  The type of the address of a `sys_mutex_t` boils down to `struct sys_sem **`, which is the correct type for the call.

> So I can pass anything to sys_mutex_lock, can't I?

C explicitly permits any value of integer type to be converted to any pointer type, and vise versa.  C also permits a pointer to any object type to be converted to a pointer to any other object type.  Compliant C compilers *must* be able to compile such statements because C allows them, and I would expect any compiler to accept them by default.

On the other hand, whether the result of such a conversion is meaningful or appropriate is an entirely different question.  Many such conversions yield undefined behavior, and many others yield defined, but unwanted behavior.  As a result, any C compiler worth its salt should issue warnings about such conversions, at least when they are implicit, provided that such warnings are not manually disabled.

The upshot is that yes, the compiler should allow you to pass any integer or pointer argument to `sys_mutex_lock()`, but it should warn you if you try to pass any value that is not of type `struct sys_sem **`.  It seems that is indeed what you observe.

Overall, I don't see anything wrong with any of the compiler behaviors you describe.

Comment: I think I got you. `You are confusing the address-of operator (&) with the dereferencing operator (*).` That was my mistake. So `&sys_mutex_t` means `&(*sys_sem)` which means the address of the pointer. And the address of the pointer corresponds to a double pointer

Comment: Yes.  The address of a pointer is a pointer to a pointer. I prefer that terminology, or perhaps "pointer pointer", but you could as well call it a double pointer.